# There has been vs There had been

Tags: grammar, meaning, semantic-roles

How and where should we use "There has been" and "There had been"?

For example, I cannot recognize the semantic difference between the two following sentences:

> There had been such a fortunate occurrence.
>
> There has been such a fortunate occurrence.

In general, I know the grammars of past perfect and present perfect, but the translator translates them (the above examples) alike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There **had been** such a fortunate occurrence.
>   Something amazing **had happened**.  *For a day, money* ***dropped*** *from the sky!*

This recounts an event that *happened* in the past but has now passed.

---

> There **has been** such a fortunate occurrence.
>   Something amazing **has happened**. *Money* ***is dropping*** *from the sky!*

This recounts an event that *started* in the past but is still ongoing.